# Google Maps returns null on location update

Tags: android, google-maps

For weeks I'm getting null pointer exception, when the program tries to put a marker on the map. I don't know why, I tried couple of solutions, but they did not work. I am getting this error on several devices. For instance, there is no error on 100 devices but in 5 or more devices this error is being occured.
Also I am not able to use .getMap() function. There is just getMapAsync available.

Here is the error that I obtain from Firebase:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.animateCamera(com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate)' on a null object reference
```

Here is the Google Maps fragment:

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/map1"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="com.ahmetbesli.eczanem.MapsActivityPicker"
        />
```

Here is the code of my program:

```
public class MapsActivityPicker extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, View.OnClickListener {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
        GoogleMap mGoogleMap;
        SupportMapFragment mapFrag;
        LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
        GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
        Location mLastLocation;
        Marker mCurrLocationMarker;
        FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationClient;
        LocationManager mLocationManager;

        ArrayList<MarkerData> markers = new ArrayList<>();
        int counter = 1;
        int resumeCounter = 2;
        boolean add = true;
        LatLng midLatLng;
        LatLng latLngMaps;

        ImageView direction;
        ImageView bullet;
        ImageView share;
        ImageView nearMe;
        ImageView call;
        CountDownTimer timer;
        String pharmacyName;
        String pharmacyAddress;
        String markerPhone = null;
        Double markerLatitude;
        Double markerLongitude;

        private InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;
        String shortURL;
        LocationCallback mLocationCallback;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps_picker);




            mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);

            mapFrag = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map1);
            buildGoogleApiClient();
            mapFrag.getMapAsync(this);
            mLocationManager = (LocationManager) MapsActivityPicker.this
                    .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

            direction = findViewById(R.id.directionPicker);
            bullet = findViewById(R.id.bulletPicker);
            share = findViewById(R.id.sharePicker);
            nearMe = findViewById(R.id.accessPicker);
            call = findViewById(R.id.callPicker);

            direction.setOnClickListener(this);
            bullet.setOnClickListener(this);
            share.setOnClickListener(this);
            nearMe.setOnClickListener(this);
            call.setOnClickListener(this);

            sharedPreferences = this.getApplication().getSharedPreferences(Config.app_name,MODE_PRIVATE);

            mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
            mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("xxxxxxxxxx");
            mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());


            timer = new CountDownTimer(5000, 1000)
            {
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                }

                public void onFinish() {
                    if (add) {
                        if (mInterstitialAd != null) {
                            if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                                mInterstitialAd.show();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
            timer.start();
        }

        @Override
        public void onPause() {
            super.onPause();

            if (mFusedLocationClient != null) {
                mFusedLocationClient.removeLocationUpdates(mLocationCallback);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onMapReady(final GoogleMap googleMap) {

            mGoogleMap = googleMap;
            mGoogleMap.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(false);
            mGoogleMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new CustomInfoWindowAdapter(MapsActivityPicker.this));
            mGoogleMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
                public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {
                    bullet.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    share.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    direction.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    nearMe.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    call.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            });
            mGoogleMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MapsActivityPicker.this, HomePageShared.class);
                    intent.putExtra("name",marker.getTitle());
                    intent.putExtra("address",marker.getSnippet());
                    intent.putExtra("phone",markerPhone);
                    intent.putExtra("latitude",marker.getPosition().latitude);
                    intent.putExtra("longitude",marker.getPosition().longitude);
                    intent.putExtra("userLatitude", midLatLng.latitude);
                    intent.putExtra("userLongitude",midLatLng.longitude);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
            mGoogleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
                Marker currentShown;
                @Override
                public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {

                    if (marker.equals(currentShown)) {
                        marker.hideInfoWindow();
                        currentShown = null;
                    } else {
                        marker.showInfoWindow();
                        currentShown = marker;
                    }

                    pharmacyName = marker.getTitle();
                    pharmacyAddress = marker.getSnippet();
                    markerLatitude = marker.getPosition().latitude;
                    markerLongitude = marker.getPosition().longitude;

                    for(int i = 0; i < markers.size(); i++){
                        if(markers.get(i).getName().equals(pharmacyName)){
                            markerPhone = markers.get(i).getPhone();
                        }
                    }


                    shortURL = "http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=" + markerLatitude + "," + markerLongitude;


                    latLngMaps = marker.getPosition();
                    share.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    direction.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    bullet.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    nearMe.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    call.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    return true;
                }

            });

            googleMap.setOnCameraIdleListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraIdleListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCameraIdle() {
                    //get latlng at the center by calling
                    midLatLng = googleMap.getCameraPosition().target;
                    //request();
                    requestRetrofit();
                    googleMap.clear();

                }
            });
            if(sharedPreferences.getBoolean(Config.theme,false)){
                mGoogleMap.setMapStyle(MapStyleOptions.loadRawResourceStyle(this, R.raw.night_mode));
            }
        }

        protected void getGPS() {
            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    this);
            alertDialogBuilder
                    .setMessage("Konum Servisiniz kapalı. Eczaneleri görebilmek için lütfen açınız.")
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton("Konum Servisini Aç",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                                    int id) {
                                    Intent callGPSSettingIntent = new Intent(
                                            android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                                    MapsActivityPicker.this.startActivity(callGPSSettingIntent);
                                }
                            });
            alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Kapalı Kalsın",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });
            AlertDialog alert = alertDialogBuilder.create();
            alert.show();
        }

        public void requestRetrofit(){
            ApiInterface apiInterface = ApiClient.getRetrofit().create(ApiInterface.class);
            Call<ArrayList<Eczane>> call = apiInterface.getPharmacies(new com.ahmetbesli.eczanem.Request(String.valueOf(midLatLng.latitude),String.valueOf(midLatLng.longitude)));
            call.enqueue(new Callback<ArrayList<Eczane>>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<ArrayList<Eczane>> call, retrofit2.Response<ArrayList<Eczane>> response) {
                    markers.clear();
                    if (response.body().get(0) != null) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                            if (!response.body().get(i).getLatitude().equals("undefined") && !response.body().get(i).getLongitude().equals("undefined") && !response.body().get(i).getLatitude().equals("") && !response.body().get(i).getLongitude().equals("")) {
                                createMarker(Double.valueOf(response.body().get(i).getLatitude()),
                                        Double.valueOf(response.body().get(i).getLongitude()), response.body().get(i).getName(),
                                        response.body().get(i).getAdress(), response.body().get(i).getPhone(), R.mipmap.marker);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<ArrayList<Eczane>> call, Throwable t) {

                }
            });
        }

        protected void starter() {
            //Initialize Google Play Services
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                        == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    //Location Permission already granted
                    buildGoogleApiClient();
                } else {
                    //Request Location Permission
                    checkLocationPermission();
                }
            } else {
                buildGoogleApiClient();
            }
        }

        protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                    .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                    .build();
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }

        @Override
        public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
            mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
            mLocationRequest.setInterval(120000); // two minute interval
            mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(120000);
            mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                mFusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, mLocationCallback, Looper.myLooper());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        }

        public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION = 99;

        private void checkLocationPermission() {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                // Should we show an explanation?
                if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {

                    // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
                    // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
                    // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.
                    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                            .setTitle("Konum Servisi için izin gerekli.")
                            .setMessage("Bu uygulama konum servisi iznine ihtiyaç duymaktadır. Lütfen kabul ediniz.")
                            .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                    //Prompt the user once explanation has been shown
                                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MapsActivityPicker.this,
                                            new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                                            MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);
                                }
                            })
                            .create()
                            .show();


                } else {
                    // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                            new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                            MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String permissions[], @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
            switch (requestCode) {
                case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION: {
                    // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                    if (grantResults.length > 0
                            && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                        // permission was granted, yay! Do the
                        // location-related task you need to do.
                        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                            if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
                                buildGoogleApiClient();
                            }
                        }

                    } else {
                        // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                        // functionality that depends on this permission.
                        Toast.makeText(this, "İzin Reddedildi", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }

                // other 'case' lines to check for other
                // permissions this app might request
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
            if (resumeCounter <= 2) {
                starter();
                resumeCounter++;
            }
            if (counter == 0) {
                if (mLocationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
                    starter();
                    counter++;
                } else {
                    getGPS();
                    counter++;
                }
            }
        }

        protected void createMarker(double latitude, double longitude, String title, String snippet, String phone, int iconResID) {
            MarkerData marker = new MarkerData(title, snippet, phone, latitude, longitude);
            markers.add(marker);

            mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude))
                    .anchor(0.5f, 0.5f)
                    .title(title)
                    .snippet(snippet)
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(iconResID)));
        }

        @Override
        protected void onStart(){
            super.onStart();
            mLocationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
                    for (Location location : locationResult.getLocations()) {
                        mLastLocation = location;
                        if (mCurrLocationMarker != null) {
                            mCurrLocationMarker.remove();
                        }

                        mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()), 10.7f));
                    }
                }
            };
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `onStart` method you are calling  `mGoogleMap.animateCamera()` probably at a time when it is not assigned. It is being assigned in `onMapReady`
you need to check to see if it is null.

```
if(mGoogleMap != null){
    mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()), 10.7f));
}
```

I suspect that you have a race condition: on some devices the `onMapReady()` method is being called before `onLocationResult()`...so everything works fine. But on other devices `onLocationResult()` is called before the `onMapReady()` method and therefore mGoogleMap is `null`! Therefore, you must check to see if "mGoogleMap" has been assigned.

Do this instead:

```
//create a class variable mLatLng
private LatLng mLatLng;
```

Now change the code in your `onLocationResult()` method to look like this:

```
public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
    for (Location location : locationResult.getLocations()) {
        mLastLocation = location;
        if (mCurrLocationMarker != null) {
            mCurrLocationMarker.remove();
        }
        mLatLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        moveMapTo();
}
```

Add the method:

```
private void moveMapTo(){
    if(mLatLng == null) return;

    if(mGoogleMap != null){
        mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 10.7f));
    }
}
```

And in `onMapReady()` method all you need is to add:

```
moveMapTo();
```

This way when `onLocationResult()` is called before `onMapReady()` the variable "mLatLng" is defined and valid, but "mGoogleMap" is null--which would cause an error. As soon as "mGoogleMap" is properly defined in `onMapReady()` `moveMapTo()` is called again and your animate to the proper location. If, however, `onMapReady()` is called before  `onLocationResult()` then "mGoogleMap" is already assigned and in  `onLocationResult()` everything works as intended.

Comment: but then it will not animate the camera, it will just give it up as it is loaded. It must zoom into the location. That is my program's base case.

Comment: It will never animate the camera when it is `null`. My suspecion is that on some devices the `onMapReady()` method is being called before `onLocationResult()`...so everything works fine. But on other devices `onLocationResult()` is called before the `onMapReady()` method and therefore `mGoogleMap` is null! Therefore, you must check to see if  `mGoogleMap` has been assigned.

Comment: @AhmetAzizBeşli :: Take a look at my edit. I think this might explain.

Comment: how does this code do this operation that you explained? I understand the logic behind the code according to your explanation. But how it calls moveToMap() method when mGoogleMap is initialized? or you want me to add moveToMap() method into onMapReady() ?

Comment: By adding the method `moveMapTo()` you have a way to animate to a new location on the map. Calling  `moveMapTo()` in both `onMapReady()` and `onLocationResult()` you are setting up the situation that  `moveMapTo()` is being called twice. But it is being ignored when either the location is not defined or the mGoogleMap is not define. So it is effectively insuring, that `moveMapTo()` is being called when both have been defined... The race condition is now irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

i had same problem This problem occurs because assign map take time
you have to delay a 0.5 seconds in coroutine scope

```
       lifecycleScope.launchWhenCreated {
       delay(500L)
       val latu = LatLng(50.0145602,36.3245941)
       map?.animateCamera(
           CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
               latu
               ,
               16f
           )
       )
   }
```

now map animateCamera run after the map is assign